# Is there a society for the descendants of Mayflower passenger William Bradford?

Tags: genealogical-societies

[Wiliam Bradford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Bradford_%28Plymouth_governor%29) (March 19, 1590 – May 9, 1657) came over on the Mayflower, was governor, 
and was one of the original clebrebrants of Thanksgiving. 
Descendants are eligible for joining the Mayflower Society.
Is there a genealogical society for his descendants?
I searched on the internet and found some references 
to the Society of Governor William Bradford Descendants at http://www.sgwbd.com/
but the website doesn't appear to be working.
Is any one a member? Can they direct me to how to contact the society.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a member but have done some web searches. I can't find an active society listing for a genealogy society for the William Bradford.

The last time the website you listed was online archived was Feb 2, 2011. I was able to dig around a bit on the archived info and got an application form to come up that lists this as the person to send applications to:

Carol Scarborough 
Society of Governor Wm. Bradford Descendants, Inc.
820 Morning Star Circle
China Spring, Texas  76633-3314
E-Mail Shewulf82@aol.com

No idea if that is defunct or not but it may be a starting point.